# Does Entity Framework need to be "refreshed" to pick up database schema changes while site is still running?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, iis

I have an ASP.NET site using Entity Framework that was deployed to our test environment. It turned out that the test database was not up to date with schema changes. We were getting errors such as:

> Resource not found for the segment 'myTableName'.

We subsequently updated the database schema (we confirmed the schema is now identical to the development database schema we were using previously), but we are still getting the same errors.

Note: at this point the .edmx matches what the schema of the database is, as it was up to date with the dev database, and the test database schema is now identical.

Does Entity Framework need to somehow "refresh" its view of the database schema (say by restarting the IIS site), or should it be aware of the schema changes on each page request?

I know I could just try restarting the IIS site and see if it fixes it (I work for a large company and have already put in the request but it takes a long time), but I would like to understand what exactly is going on.

EDIT

Ok to clarify, we already updated the .edmx when we first made the schema changes (in the dev database). The site works just fine in the development environment. We deployed to test assuming the database had the exact same schema but it didn't and we updated the schema while the site was still running.

Comment: Have you right clicked in your edmx designer and clicked `Update Model from Database`?

Comment: Yes you will need to update your edmx file to be up to date with database. Which means you probably need to deploy again.

Comment: @paqogomez We did this already when we first changed the schema. Everything works fine in development environment.

Comment: @paqogomez We had not deployed to test in a while, hence the schema being out of data.

Comment: I see, so you've updated your database to match your edmx.  You just did so after the edmx was deployed.

Comment: @paqogomez Yes, exactly.